# Restricting User Access to GCP for Data Studio to Big Query connection

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I've created a Data Studio report which uses a BigQuery view as it's data source.

I've successfully managed to get differentiated row-level access for different users implemented but to do this I've had to give "BigQuery Job User" access to the users of the report in my Google Cloud project.

Has anyone found a way to do this without doing that? Although the users can't do much other than see the view's query and run queries against it in BigQuery with only the data they have access to (that I'm aware of), I'd prefer them not to be able to view the project at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the access and choose "Use owners credentials"
See https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6371135

If you think it's too risky, because you have too many rights: create a new google account with limited "BigQuery Job User" access to the project and make it the owner of the data studio report (and then use "Use owners credentials").

Comment: Thanks Martin. I can't use my credentials as it would give them access to all data where I only want them to get a sub-set.

I don't want them to have ownership of the report either as its a shared report for many user, all with different sub-sets of data.

The current set-up works in having a single report which gives every user a different data set based on their needs, I just don't want them to be able to see anything in BQ ideally.

Comment: Would it make sense to only share the specific dataset with them instead of the whole project?

Comment: Yeah they only have access to the single view already, not the whole project.

I was just hoping for a way which didn't give them any way to view the data except through the report but I'm guessing its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use owner credentials in your Data Source, with a custom query implementing your row-level access using the special @DS_USER_EMAIL variable.

See https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713766?hl=en